# Level converter with noisy output

Tags: operational-amplifier, digital-logic, level-shifting

I have the following circuit setup to feed a sine wave into a microcontroller. This converts the sine wave into a square wave so I can measure the frequency. The output of the opamp (U1 - [OPA4830](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/opa4830.pdf)) looks perfect until I connect it to the level shifter (U2 - [TXS0108E](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/txs0108e.pdf)). Then, it develops "bounces" on the rising and falling edges. This is a problem since these bounces can trigger my interrupt controller. Why does introducing this level converter cause this noise in the system?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Those look like the edge accelerators of the TXS. Why did you choose it?

Comment: Can you add a picture of the physical wiring of the chips so that we can get an idea of what your circuit looks like in real life?  For example, there could be issues from the connectivity of the power supplies or the chips, but we can't tell without some idea of how things are physically connected.

Comment: @CL., I had used it on other board designs because it had 8 channels and was able to handle both push-pull and open drain, making it highly versatile.

Comment: @CL., are you saying that the one-shot accelerators are kicking in at the bounce but the op amp output is too slow and ends up overpowering them?

Comment: No, the one-shots kick in only for a short time (the capacitance of the line appears to be much too large for them to reach the target voltage on time), and when they stop, you get a little bit of ringing.

Comment: @CL., add that as an answer and I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: @CL., would changing U1 from an op amp to a comparator help?

Comment: Are these waveforms from the A side or the B side? How does the other side look?

Comment: Do you have proper, close-by 100 nF decoupling capacitors on each supply as indicated in the example circuit in the datasheet?

Comment: @CL. These are from the A (3.3V) side. The B side has the same problem.

Comment: Please show the actual board or wiring.